# How do I add a value to an object in an array that is the value of a key in another object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object named `session`. It looks like this:

```
{ 
  "cookie":   
              {
                  "expires": null
              },
  "toDo": 
          [
              {
                  "name": Taylor,
                  "id": 0,
                  "location": boston
              }
          ]
}
```

I want to add another key-value pair for the temperature to the group under `"toDo"`.

I've tried `session.toDo.push({'temp; 65});` but I end up with this:

```
{ 
  "cookie":   
              {
                 "expires": null
              },
  "toDo": 
         [
              {
                  "name": Taylor,
                  "id": 0,
                  "location": boston
              },
              {
                  "temp": 65
              }
          ]
}
```

What I want is this:

```
{ 
  "cookie":   
              {
                 "expires": null
              },
  "toDo": 
         [
              {
                  "name": Taylor,
                  "id": 0,
                  "location": boston,
                  "temp": 65
              }
          ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the first item in the array:

`session.toDo[0].temp = 65`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Follow-up question: how would I later access that value?

Comment: Same way `session.toDo[0].temp`